# Finding missing file from directory using bash script and prinitng

Tags: bash, shell

I have files in directory  like 111.print.save, 111.con.save ,snap-con-123-12-3-full.tgz and i want to check with pre defined accepted file which are defined in array. can use any number instead of 111.
The issue is that lets say that if i have 111.con.save missing than the output shows snap-con-*-full.tgz and con.save missing even though i have sanp-con file.

```
ACCEPTED_FILES=("print.save" "con.save" "snap-con-*-full.tgz")
FILE_LIST=(`find $PARENT_DIR/$dns  -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -mtime 0 -name "*$term_id*"| awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' | tr '\n' ' '`)

MISSING_FILE=()
for search_file in ${ACCEPTED_FILES[@]}; do
  if [[ "${FILE_LIST[*]}" == *"$search_file"*  ]]; then
    Message "File found $search_file"
  else
    #MISSING_FILES="${MISSING_FILES} $search_file"
    MISSING_FILES+=($search_file)
  fi
done
echo "Missing Files: ${MISSING_FILES[*]}"
```

Comment: The `*` in `snap-con-*-full.tgz` is evaluated verbatim (not as a pattern) since the `$search_file` is quoted in the `if` condition.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I don't think this is the problem. Since the array expansion is unquoted in the loop, `$search_file` should already iterate over all the matches of `*-full.tgz`. You can test this with `a=("*"); for i in ${a[@]}; do echo "$i"; done`. Even though `"$i"` is quoted, it prints the content of your working directory.

Comment: @SumitDuwai Please [edit] your question so that we can reproduce the problem. That is, specify a minimal file tree. At the moment it is not clear where your `snap-con-...-full.tgz` files are. Maybe you have some in `$PARENT_DIR/$dns` but none in the current working directory. Also, please try to explain your final goal in detail -- I'm sure there is an easier solution.

Comment: @Socowi Right but we don't know what the current directory is. So it may or may not iterate over all the matches of *-full.tgz. Note that `FILE_LIST` contains basenames only. Anyway, this method is very fragile.

Comment: @Socowi I am writing program to maintain backup of specific file (ACCEPTED_FILES) of $PARENT_DIR/$dns folder show it search for file and copy the file in backup folder and send message of the files that are missing  my code is working for all the files except for snap-con. If  none of my files are missing it backsup all file including the snap-con file but if even one files is missing (con.save) than backup is made for print.save but not for snap as its show that it missing along with con.save

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

accepted_files=('print.save' 'con.save' 'snap-con-*-full.tgz')
missing_files=()

for search_file in "${accepted_files[@]}"; do
    if [[ -z $(find "$PARENT_DIR/$dns"  -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -mtime 0 -name "*$term_id*" -name "*$search_file*") ]]
    then missing_files+=("$search_file"); fi
done

echo "Missing Files: ${missing_files[*]}"
```

The snippet above may not be efficient but it should be more robust.